Genesis | Why weren't other land creatures blessed on the 6th day?
I've been looking over the creation with an eye towards the 10 utterances of creation ("Then God said...") and other instances where God spoke or blessed something.
In Genesis 1:22, God blesses the creatures of the sea and the birds of the air - and says to be fruitful and multiply.
In Genesis 1:29, God blesses mankind - and says to be fruitful and multiply, to fill the earth and subdue it, and to rule over all other creatures in the earth and seas and the birds of the air.
In Genesis 2:3, God blesses the 7th day and sanctifies it - but notably it is not written that he says anything on this occasion.
What I find interesting here is that during the creation creatures of the sea and the birds of the air and man were all blessed - but other creatures made on the 6th day were NOT blessed. Why were they denied a blessing?
I also just noticed something else interesting (but not part of the question): there are precisely 12 occurrences during the creation where it is written that God said something; 2 of them being blessings.

Rashi on Genesis 1:22 writes that G-d chose not to bless the land animals, as that would have included blessing the soon-to-be-accursed serpent.
Ramban ad loc. suggests that the blessing of the fish on the fifth day applied to the land animals as well.
Genesis Rabbah 11:3 (at least according to some interpretations) considers the blessing of man on the sixth day to also apply to the animals created on the sixth day.

Interesting points. I especially like Rashi's insight. More explanation would be needed for the idea that man's blessing also applies to the land creatures since the blessing includes ruling over those same land creatures.
